# Create a summarized table using data from table.

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table which displays the following information:

```
order#   orderdate   Company   Itemno    itemdesc    sales   qty    price    location    ref#    dept.      discount   approvedstatus    ordertype   subrent

AH123   01/23/2013    HRV   T1456286    dog leash   T       50     10.00      LA         NR     ACESSORIES    0.00      APPROV     
AH123   01/23/2013    HRV   T1456286    dog bone   T        10     10.00      LA         AF     ACESSORIES    0.00      APPROV           O             F
TV1245  05/25/2013    T&T   T54895      staples              5     10.00     AB         ARC      SUPPLIES     0.00      APPROV           O             F      
TV1645  05/25/2013    T&T   T54895      paper               10     20.00     AB         ARC      SUPPLIES     0.00      APPROV           O             F
```

Given this table I would like to get a summarized table which would give me the following information:

```
Location      Rev       Non-Rev
LA         100.00      500.00
AB         250.00      0.00
```

In Order words, the total_Price based on the location will only go into Non-Rev if the ref# says 'NR' otherwise it will go into REV column.

I have tried this by inserting everything to a temp table and then using a case statement but I can't use CASE WHEN ref#<>'NR' SUM(price_qty) as it requires me to group it by ref# as well which creates more column than I actually need.

Any help!!!

Answer (score 1):

You were really close:

```
SELECT  Location,
        SUM(CASE WHEN [ref#] = 'NR' THEN price_qty END) Rev,
        SUM(CASE WHEN [ref#] <> 'NR' THEN price_qty END) [Non-Rev]
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY Location
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I follow, but I think you can use a derived table, which would be your detail plus your derived rev and non-rev columns, and then summarize from that.
Something like:

```
select
col1,
...
sum(NonRev),
sum(rev)
from
(
select Col1,
...,
case when ref# <> 'NR' then price_qty else 0 end as NonRev,
case when ref# = 'NR' then price_qty else 0 end as rev
from
yourtable
) t1
group by 
col1,
...
```